# Cant fix Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I need some help here.

Keep getting a Null Pointer Exception after the part that is says "Your code has been generated." when I run my code and I can't figure out why.

It was working fine before I added the asHex class in a new java file in the same package but now it doesn't work even after removing the asHex.

Can anyone help me out?

Code:

```
public class myDesCbc2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {


        JFrame frame = null;
        JFileChooser fChoose = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        int returnVal = fChoose.showOpenDialog(frame);
        File myFile = fChoose.getSelectedFile();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "ISO-8859-1"));
        String file;
        while ((file = stream.readLine()) != null) {

            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                    null, "Generating a 56-bit DES key...", "Processing...", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);

        }
        // Create an 8-byte initialization vector
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] iv = new byte[8];
        sr.nextBytes(iv);
        IvParameterSpec IV = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        // Create a 56-bit DES key
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");

        // Initialize with keysize
        kg.init(56);
        Key mykey = kg.generateKey();

        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                null, "Your key has been generated!", "Processing...", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);

        // Create a cipher object and use the generated key to initialize it
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mykey, IV);

        byte[] plaintext = file.getBytes("UTF8");

        // Encrypt the text
        byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "Your ciphertext is" + asHex(ciphertext), "Done!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

asHex code:

```
public class asHex {
      public static String asHex (byte buf[]) {
         StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(buf.length * 2);
         int i;

           for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
              if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10)
                strbuf.append("0");

                strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
              }

           return strbuf.toString();
  }

}
```

Comment: Please, edit your post with the error [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)

Comment: If you want to be a good programmer you should read [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: And flag the line of code that throws the exception

Comment: Check the closing bracket of the while loop, shouldn't it be at the end?

Comment: Thanks @RafaEl ill take note of that for future programs!

Comment: @user3180947 Please accept the answer if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code after while loop within the while loop, that should resolve the issue. Else, the file is null when the code after while loop is executed leading to the error.